# Append rectangle to line graph to show weekends

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learing how to plot graphs with D3 and I want to plot on the graph an area ,or similar, to indicate that the dates of the weekend are different than the rest (I have attach and image to explain myself better). What I have right now is the Fiddle I show later.

As you can see, on the data, there are days that don't have values and their respective days are missing.

JSFiddle of what I have accoplish right now:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Critter/TJqE6/2/)

```
var data = [
  {"date":"1-May-13","close":58.13},
  {"date":"30-Apr-13","close":53.98},
  {"date":"27-Apr-13","close":67.00},
  {"date":"26-Apr-13","close":89.70},
  {"date":"25-Apr-13","close":99.00},
  {"date":"24-Apr-13","close":130.28},
  {"date":"23-Apr-13","close":166.70},
  {"date":"20-Apr-13","close":234.98},
  {"date":"19-Apr-13","close":345.44},
  {"date":"18-Apr-13","close":443.34},
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return "$" + formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
```

And an image of what I want to accomplish:

[image: Graph with weekend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your x scale domain, which can be better defined with:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
}))
```

We can populate an array with all the Saturdays between the first date (which is `x.domain()[0]`) and the last date (which is `x.domain()[1]`). We only need to find the Saturdays: the bars' width will be Saturday + 2 days (which will cover the whole Saturday and the whole Sunday).

There are several functions to do this, here is one:

```
function findSat(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) return false;
    var saturdays = [];
    while (date1 < date2) {
        if (date1.getDay() === 6) saturdays.push(new Date(date1));
        date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return saturdays;
}
```

Using that function, we can populate an array with all the Saturdays between your first and last date:

```
var rectDate = findSat(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]);
```

Now, we use that `rectDate` array to create the rectangles:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
    .data(rectDate)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("height", height - margin.bottom)
    .attr("x", d => x(d))
    .attr("width", d => x(d3.time.day.offset(d, +2)) - x(d))
    .attr("fill", "yellow");
```

Notice that, for the width, we subtract "Saturday + 2 days" from Saturday:

```
.attr("width", d => x(d3.time.day.offset(d, +2)) - x(d))
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36yaot6t/

And here the same code, in a Stack snippet:

```js
var data = [{
    "date": "1-May-13",
    "close": 58.13
}, {
    "date": "30-Apr-13",
    "close": 53.98
}, {
    "date": "27-Apr-13",
    "close": 67.00
}, {
    "date": "26-Apr-13",
    "close": 89.70
}, {
    "date": "25-Apr-13",
    "close": 99.00
}, {
    "date": "24-Apr-13",
    "close": 130.28
}, {
    "date": "23-Apr-13",
    "close": 166.70
}, {
    "date": "20-Apr-13",
    "close": 234.98
}, {
    "date": "19-Apr-13",
    "close": 345.44
}, {
    "date": "18-Apr-13",
    "close": 443.34
}, ];

var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
        return d.date;
    }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) {
        return "$" + formatValue(d);
    };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.close);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
}))
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.close;
}));

function findSat(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) return false;
    var saturdays = [];
    while (date1 < date2) {
        if (date1.getDay() === 6) saturdays.push(new Date(date1));
        date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return saturdays;
}

var rectDate = findSat(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]);

var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
    .data(rectDate)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("height", height - margin.bottom)
    .attr("x", d => x(d))
    .attr("width", d => x(d3.time.day.offset(d, +2)) - x(d))
    .attr("fill", "yellow");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price ($)");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5);

focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.close) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.close));
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mmm... I think it could be better if I take into account if the first day is Sunday. So I will include in the while: "if (date1.getDay() === 0) saturdays.push(new Date(date1));" and make it substract only one day on: ".attr("width", d => x(d3.time.day.offset(d, +1)) - x(d))"

Comment: If you do this, you'll only get the Sunday: http://jsfiddle.net/45j3k3x5/

Comment: Well, I was refering to add a new line to take into account the Saturdays and Sundays: http://jsfiddle.net/45j3k3x5/1/

Comment: You don't need to get the Sundays. The day after the Saturday is always a Sunday. Just get the Saturdays and make the bar width a 2-day interval. However, your solution works better if **the first date** in your data array is a Sunday. Otherwise, you are only drawing two rectangles when you could draw only one.

Comment: You are correct. But I have added that because my data is dynamic, and can start on Sundays, and end before a Saturday. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yep, I realised that this was the reason for you to get the Sundays.